# How to eliminate element from an arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, extends

I am currently working on my homework which is simulation to an alarm, I have a method called `removeAlarm()` , I wanna force remove the alarm which I added, I tried `alarm.remove(0)` and tried to iterator but in the test program the alarm is still there.
Does anyone observe the issue?

```
private ArrayList<String> alarm;

    public AlarmClock() throws IllegalValueException {
        super();
        alarm = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    public AlarmClock(int hour, int minute) throws IllegalValueException {
        super(hour, minute);
        alarm = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addAlarm(int hour, int minute) throws IllegalValueException {
        int limit = 2;
        int length = String.valueOf(hour).length();
        String displayValue = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < limit - length; i++) {
            displayValue = displayValue + "0";
        }

        displayValue = displayValue + hour + ":";
        limit = 2;
        length = String.valueOf(minute).length();
        for (int i = 0; i < limit - length; i++) {
            displayValue = displayValue + "0";
        }
        displayValue = displayValue + minute;

        alarm.add(displayValue);

    }


    public void removeAlarm() {
if (alarm.equals(getClass())) {
        alarm.remove(alarm.equals(getTime()));
        }

    }
super.timeTick();
        for (int x = 0; x < alarm.size(); x++) {
            if (alarm.get(x).equals(getTime())) {
                System.out.println("LARMET ÄR KLARR, VAKNAAAAA");
                alarm.remove(x);

            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
```

My test program

```
try {
            AlarmClock alarm = new AlarmClock(12, 3);
            alarm.timeTick();
            System.out.println(alarm.getTime());
            alarm.timeTick();
            System.out.println(alarm.getTime());
            alarm.removeAlarm();
            alarm.addAlarm(12, 6);
            alarm.timeTick();
            System.out.println(alarm.getTime());

        } catch (IllegalValueException a) {

            System.out.println(a.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println("Expected: alarm removed at 12:06 ");
        System.out.println(" ");
```

```
Output
12:04
12:05
LARMET ÄR KLARR, VAKNAAAAA
12:06
Expected: alarm removed at 12:06
```

Comment: Your `removeAlarm()` method is empty.  Of course it doesn't remove anything from the list.

Comment: I put alarm.remove(0) the same result is occurred

Comment: Asaranow, you need to post the code you think is wrong, otherwise we can't help you. Please edit your question.

Comment: To answer debugging questions such as this one, we need a [mre] to review.  What you have presented is not one.  In fact it's not even all that close.  Not only do we need to see the actual `removeAlarm()` method you are testing, but we need to see a complete class under test and a complete test program.  But not more in either of those than is necessary to demonstrate the problem.  I should be able to copy your code to a file or files, compile it as-is, and see the misbehavior when I run the result.

Comment: Regarding your edits: the `removeAlarm()` implementation now presented is *nothing like* I imagined from your description.  This is why we ask for an MRE.  With regard to that implementation, under what circumstances do you imagine that the expression `alarm.equals(getClass())` would ever evaluate to true?  And if somehow it did, what makes you think that `alarm.remove(alarm.equals(getTime()));` would ever remove anything from a `List<String>`?

Comment: `if (alarm.equals(getClass())) {` this condition is never, ever true. `alarm` is an `ArrayList<String>`, and the `getClass` method returns a `Class<?>`. As a beginner, you should probably never be calling the `getClass` method, since it's an advanced feature that isn't usually taught about at such an early stage, and won't be needed to solve any of your assignments.

Comment: what does getTime do? the implementation not specified in the question's description?

Answer (score 0):

alarm.remove(0) will remove the first item in the list. To remove an item from anywhere in the list the function would have to be

```
void removeAlarm(int target) {

  alarm.remove(target);

}
```

or

```
void removeAlarm(int hour, int min) {

  alarm.remove{hour+":"+min);
}
```

for just removing the last alarm:

```
void removeLastAlarm() {

  alarm.remove(alarm.size()-1);
}
```